# Reset counter when not in range and sum progression

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an arrays of numbers, and specified range if sequence continues (range rule was met between two numbers) then i add value to result and increase counter by one, else i reset the counter and add nothing to result on this step. Better show in an example:

```js
const numbers = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 33, 44, 46]; // they are always going to be from smallest to bigger

const progress = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]; // 70, 80, etc

let res = 0;

for (let i = 1, j = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  const range = numbers[i] - numbers[i - 1];

  if (range <= 5) {
   j += 1;
   res += progress[j];
  } else {
   j = 0;
  }
}

res; // 110
```

Is there better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Does `progress[j]` always equal `10 * j`?

Comment: no, its just for example, it can be 15, 25, w/e step, but lets assume min step is 5

Comment: OK; does it always form an arithmetic progression?

Comment: yes, from smaller to bigger

Comment: An _arithmetic progression_, that is with the _constant_ step?

Comment: no, step can be different like 5, 25, 30, 40

Answer (score 0):

Well, by looking at your code & the explanation you gave, I think you have incremented 'j' before you added progress for 'j'. that portion should be like following...

```
if (range <= 5) {
   res += progress[j];
   j += 1;  
}
```

You have asked for a better approach. But it would help if you specified from which perspective/scenario you are looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same with reduce method

```
const numbers = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 33, 44, 46]; // they are always going to be from smallest to bigger

const progress = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]; // 70, 80, etc

let resp = 0;

const result = numbers.reduce((acc, rec, i, arr) => {
  if (rec - arr[i - 1] <= 5) {
    resp += 1;
    acc = acc + progress[resp];
    return acc;
  }
  resp = 0;
  return acc;
}, 0);

result;
```

[You can read more about reduce here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Hope it answers your question.

Happy coding!